# Searching users with WP_List_Table plugin

Tags: plugins, php, mysql, wp-list-table, wp-user-query

I am trying to devlope a plugin that will search and return my users so I can edit some other metatdata that belongs to them. I have been using the plug-in listed on the [Codex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-list-table-example/) as my starting point.

I have my table appearing with the the users from a WP_User_Query. But I am having issues with filtering the query with the search input.

Wildcard search *mysearch* will return the table correctly, but going to the second page returns back to a blank search. The search variable is not being placed in the url. How do I pass this to the url? (the pagination is passed only)

Also is there a way to change it so that I do not have to physically at "*" before and after the search parameters and have it done in the code?

Here is my query:

```
function prepare_items() {
    global $wpdb;

    $searchcol= array(
    'ID',
    'user_email',
    'user_login',
    'user_nicename',
    'user_url',
    'display_name'
    );

    $orderby = !empty($_GET["orderby"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["orderby"]) : 'email';
    $order = !empty($_GET["order"]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["order"]) : 'ASC';

    $args  = array(
    'fields' => 'all_with_meta', 
    'orderby' => $orderby , 
    'order' => $order , 
    'search' =>$_REQUEST["s"] ,
    'search_columns' => $searchcol
    );

    $my_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
}
```

and here is my search field:

```
    function my_render_list_table_page(){
    global $my_list_table_sample_page, $wpdb;

    $my_list_table_sample_page->prepare_items();
    <form action="" method="post" >
<?php
   $my_list_table_sample_page->search_box( __( 'Search Users' ), 'user' ); 
   $my_list_table_sample_page->display(); 
   $my_list_table_sample_page->display();
   echo '</form>'; 
}
```

Comment: Found the parameter 'search_columns' for WP_User_Query then created an array with 'ID', 'user_email', 'user_login', 'user_nicename', 'user_url', 'display_name' for its parameters. Now to add wildcard to the search as it only returns full matches.

Comment: The search parameter is not being placed in the url because your form is using POST instead of GET.

Answer (score 2):

Brian is correct. By changing the form to use get instead of post and then using $_REQUEST to fetch it should work, and is for me.

```
// Fetch, prepare, sort, and filter our data.
if( isset( $_REQUEST ["s"] ) ){

// Form that displays the table and also contains the search_box()
<form id="table-class-filter" method="get" class="table-class-admin-form">
```

Answer (score 1):

As Brian noted, your form sends the data via POST, and you are fetching via GET.  Change for method to "GET" or else use the $_POST variable.  (But note that your search term is passed along using your current code, because both POST and GET populate the $_REQUEST variable).

You can make the search more flexible by ensuring that it is surrounded by wildcard (asterisk) characters.  Something like this should do the trick:

`$search = preg_replace( "^$\**(.*)\**$?#", "*$1*", $_REQUEST["s"] );`

This will allow the search input was submitted with zero or more leading/trailing asterisks, and ensure that your search string is preceded and followed by a single asterisk.